# How to express a series of integers in an if else statement?

Tags: java, android, if-statement, int

Currently I have this if else statement in my code

```
if (chosenView == findViewById(R.id.playView1) && (4 <= pointCounter && pointCounter <= 9) || (13 <= pointCounter && pointCounter <= 18) || pointCounter >= 22) { }
```

I only want what is contained within the statement to be ran if the chosenView is playView1 AND the pointCounter is equal to 4,5,6,7,8,9,13,14,15,16,17,18, or anything above 22 but I feel like this is sloppy code and not the correct way to do this. Especially since when I remove the parentheses, it gives me an error. Is this correct or is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: It looks fine to me...

Comment: Run it through a formatter. Other than that, it looks good

Answer (score 1):

If you need those specific criteria, then the way that you've written it is the simplest and fastest. (If you didn't have the open-ended "above 22", then using `Set.contains` or an array find might be a little prettier but would be slower.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Java but found the following page:

http://www.programcreek.com/2013/09/top-10-methods-for-java-arrays/

Which, suggests to me you could use something like:

```
int[] intArray = { 4,5,6,7,8,9,13,14,15,16,17,18 };
if (chosenView == findViewById(R.id.playView1) && (Arrays.asList(intArray).contains(pointCounter) || pointCounter >= 22) { }
```

Comment: This one sounds like it would work but it returns an error. ""List<int[]>' may not contain objects of type 'Integer'"

Comment: Also this is needlessly slow.